# Use tableView in prepareForSegue swift

Tags: swift, controller, segue

I have some problems with tableView in second controller

First controller's code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "DetailSegue" {
        let detailViewController = segue.destinationViewController as DetailViewController
        let indexPath = self.liveMatch!.indexPathForSelectedRow()!
    }
}
```

Second controller's code: (DetailViewController)

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // Return the number of rows in the section.
        return 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("playersCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as PlayersTableViewCell

        cell.playerName.text = "test"

        return cell
    }
}
```

Table in seconds controller is empty ;( How i can repair this? Thank u!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need conform the `UITableViewDataSource` protocol, and implement the `numberOfSectionsInTableView` method.

So add the protocol: 
`class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {`

and the method

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView?) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

Comment: return error: Method does not override any method from its superclass

Comment: Sorry, the override keyword is not necessary in this case. It's only necessary when using UITableViewController. Remove it and it should work.

Comment: tried yet. Result did not change: returns the empty columns.

Comment: Tried to add `println("test")` to tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath. Is not called

Comment: Right, you need to bind the tableView's delegate and datasource outlets to the controller from the storyboard, right know your controller doesn't know about the tableView. Look, the easiest way is to subclass UITableViewController instead of UIViewController, as it handles all this for you. Instead of `class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource` use `class DetailViewController: UITableViewController` and you may need to add the override keyword to the tableView methods you have.

Comment: If you really really can't use UITableViewController and need to use UIViewController for some reason, here's a tutorial (live page is down) https://web.archive.org/web/20150316084346/http://www.weheartswift.com/how-to-make-a-simple-table-view-with-ios-8-and-swift/ on how to do it with UIViewController with all the steps, but UITableViewController does almost all of this for you.

Comment: In addition to the table in the window displays images and labels

Comment: Well, then on the storyboard, right click the table and drag the `dataSource` and `delegate` to your ViewController (as shown in the image in the section 'Connect the Interface Builder Outlets' from the link above). I think you may also need to create an IBOutlet of the tableView to your controller.